# Maximum message size for polynomial CRC-8 0x07 and hamming distance = 3

Tags: crc, redundancy

I am looking for maximum message size for my CRC-8 0x07 polynomial for Hamming distance = 3. Do you know some website with these types of information? Or possibly, do you know how to calculate it? I couldn't find one with 0x07.

Comment: This may be off-topic for this SE site, since it is pure computer science.

Comment: This is a better fit for Stack Overflow. You may get some good responses here but you'll have much better luck on SO, I think.

Comment: Some good answers to a previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39498150

Comment: The CRC Polynomial Zoo webpage by Philip Koopman would be my first place to look at as it contains such info in general, but I cannot quarantee it contains it for the exact polynomial you need. It may contain code to calculate the maximum message length.

Comment: @Justme Thank you, you were right, he has c++ code on his website. I can do it with it. Would you mind posting an answer so I can close question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CRC Polynomial Zoo webpage by Philip Koopman would be my first place to look at as it contains such info in general, but I cannot quarantee it contains it for the exact polynomial you need. It may contain code to calculate the maximum message length.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum codeword size protected by CRC-8 0x07 (0x07 is in what [Wikipedia calls Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks) , Koopman [uses 0x83](http://blog.martincowen.me.uk/clearing-up-crc-terminology-and-representations-of-polynomials.html) to represent the same polynomial) at Hamming Distance = 3 is **119 bits**. The codeword is defined as the whole message: data word (payload) plus the Frame Check sequence (CRC in this case) so 119-8=111 bits payload.

That same CRC provides HD=4 protection to the same codeword size, but nothing beyond HD=4.

[image: CRC-8 table of polynomials against HD showing codeword length protected]

My [blog post](http://blog.martincowen.me.uk/choosing-an-optimal-crc-polynomial.html) describes how to use [my spreadsheet](http://blog.martincowen.me.uk/CRC%20Comparison.xlsx) which is derived from Prof Koopman’s data which is set up to answer questions like this in an easier format than his text files. (Requires Excel, no macros, all formulas).